# CloudFront CDN breaks due to DirectorySlash behavior of Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

My CDN domain is set to `www.mysite.com`, and it reads from `origin.mysite.com`. `mod_dir` is enabled on apache, and so any request without a trailing slash is redirected with a `301` to the equivalent URL with a trailing slash.

The issue is that when someone goes to `www.mysite.com/somepage` I would expect them to get redirected to `www.mysite.com/somepage/`, but apache issues a redirect that includes the domain name too, so the redirect issued from apache is actually `origin.mysite.com/somepage/` and the user now ends up on `origin.mysite.com` domain, and whole point of CDN is now lost.

I tried `DirectorySlash off` but that leads to numerous other problems. The solution I can think of is to have the redirect issue a relative URL, and I am not able to figure out if that is doable at all.

Comment: What does the apache httpd config look like ([`UseCanonicalName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname), [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername), etc) and what is the value of the `Host` header sent by the CDN?

Comment: `UseCanonicalName` is `Off` (default), and so `ServerName` doesn't matter that much. I fixed it like this - created a handler in my server that redirects requests coming to `/redirect/somepage` to `www.mysite.com/somepage/`, Then in my CDN i created a specific rule to look up requests specifically coming to `www.mysite.com/somepage` from a new origin, that has `/redirect` as the base url. The request now goes from `www.mysite.com/somepage` to `origin.mysite.com/redirect/somepage` which then redirects to `www.mysite.com/somepage/`. Convoluted, but works - I needed it only for specific paths

Comment: Otherwise it sounds like turning `UseCanonicalName` **on** could have been a less convoluted solution, if the CDN changes the `Host` header compared to what the original client requested?

Comment: True - But I was scared that setting the canonical name to same as the CDN domain might result in a infinite loop for some requests (not sure about it) - will need to test a bit more. It is probably the better solution in the longer term. Appreciate your advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I fixed the issue changing some wordpress parameters.

In the elasticbeanstalk I set the parameter `CUSTOM_URL` for my custom domain and in the file `/var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php` 
I set the parameters `HTTP_HOST` and `SERVER_NAME` to same value of `CUSTOM_URL`, and it resolved the redirect to elasticbeanstalk url.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['CUSTOM_URL'];

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $_SERVER['CUSTOM_URL'];
```